# Regex Search Automate Boring Stuff, functions and errors

Tags: python

I have struggled with this for hours:

```
import os, sys, re

print('Type the path to the folder.')
input_path = input()
input_path = os.path.join(input_path)
print('Select the search term')
input_term = input()
search_regex = re.compile(input_term)
all_files = os.listdir(input_path)
for j in range(len(all_files)):
    new_path = os.path.join(input_path, all_files[j])
    search_regex = re.compile(input_term)
    target_file = open(new_path, 'r')
    file_content = target_file.read()
    file_content_in_list = search_regex.findall(file_content)
    print('A grand total of ' + str(len(file_content_in_list)) + ' items were found at ' + str(new_path))
```

This works as it should be. The code reads all the files in a given folder and checks how many times a search term is found. However when i try to define the different parts of the code as functions I only get errors:

```
import os, sys, re

def select_folder():
    print('Type the path to the folder.')
    input_path = input()
    input_path = os.path.join(input_path)

def select_all_files():
    all_files = os.listdir(input_path)
    for j in range(len(all_files)):
        search_a_file()


def ask_for_regex():
    print('Select the search term')
    input_term = input()
    search_regex = re.compile(input_term)

def search_a_file():
    new_path = os.path.join(input_path, all_files[j])
    search_regex = re.compile(input_term)
    target_file = open(new_path, 'r')
    file_content = target_file.read()
    file_content_in_list = search_regex.findall(file_content)
    print('A grand total of ' + str(len(file_content_in_list)) + ' items were found at ' + str(new_path))

select_folder(): #Syntax Error here!
    ask_for_regex():
        select_all_files():



# if i put them like this then everything break down. I guess the variables are forgotten?
select_folder()
ask_for_regex()
select_all_files()
```

I suppose the mistake is obvious but I cannot comprehend it...

Comment: what are the **errors** ? the traceback provided by the console is always helpful and can pinpoint the issue.

Comment: You should read up on how parameters are passed into functions and how functions return values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you need to do some reading on returning values from functions which can then be used in other areas. I reformatted your code to show what this could look like, see if you can pick out what changes were made. I renamed some of the functions to be a little more descriptive of what they do. Also, I didn't formally test this code but it should give you a good idea of what direction you need to take it.

Also, still trying to pick up reputation points so please mark answer as accepted if it helps!

```
import os
import re


def get_folder_path():
    input_path = input('Type the path to the folder: ')
    return os.path.join(input_path)


def set_regex():
    input_term = input('Type the regex to search for: ')
    return re.compile(input_term)


def search_for_files():
    path = get_folder_path()
    search_regex = set_regex()
    file_list = os.listdir(path)
    count = 0
    for file in file_list:
        with open(file, 'r') as f:
            file_content = f.read()
            match = re.search(search_regex, file_content)
            if match:
                count += 1

    print('A grand total of ' + str(count) + ' items were found at ' + str(path))


search_for_files()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of code, analogous to your original code, that calculates the hypotenuse of a right-angled triangle in a linear fashion:

```
import math
a = 3
b = 4
c = math.sqrt(a**2 + b**2)
```

Here is the equivalent code, re-written to make it more composable, more modular:

```
import math

def hypotenuse(a, b):
    return math.sqrt(a**2 + b**2)

c = hypotenuse(3, 4)
```